# Cancel animation if ACTION_UP

Tags: android, android-animation, ontouchlistener

I have onTouchListener on my gridView and if ACTION_DOWN is pressed the animation(scale) starts. How do following things:

1. How to hold scaled image if it's ACTION_DOWN pressed
2. If is ACTION_DOWN animation is started but then if ACTION_UP (if animation is not complete)
   animation is instantly gone (back to time before animation start)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the Animation's final state to stick after it is complete, you need to call `Animation.setFillAfter(true)`

You can reset a running animation at any time with `Animation.cancel()` and `Animation.reset()` to put the view transformation back to its initial state.

HTH

Comment: I've got a problem because handling ACTION_UP is beeing done after handling ACTION_DOWN (its obvious). Starting animation is in ACTION_DOWN so animation process can't be interrupted (ACTION_UP) because animation is holding event handler (I think so)

Comment: I would suggest posting the relevant code, it sounds like you are probably declaring variables inside the wrong scope if you can't access the animation in both cases.

Comment: Yes i had problem with scopes, realy sneaky one. Everything works fine, however for interrupt animation i used also view.clearAnimation(). Thanks!